# Collection in java not getting sorted and giving error

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a list, but having problem with the comparator. My list is A and I'm trying to sort by a certain int but I'm getting error... And I can't use lamda expresion nor inheritance... Any help...

Code :

```
List<?> sortbenefitList = new ArrayList();
List<SelectItem> sortedBenefitList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for(IBen benefit : benefitList){
                Collections.sort(benefitList, benefit.getStartSegmentNumber());

                SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
                item.setValue(benefit.getBenefitId().toString());
                item.setLabel(benefit.getStartSegmentNumber().toString());
                sortedBenefitList.add(item);
            }
            if(sortedBenefitList != null && !sortedBenefitList.isEmpty()){
                Collections.sort(benefitList, benefit.getStartSegmentNumber().toString()) {

                    public int compare(SelectItem a1, SelectItem a2) {
                        String a1Lebel = a1.getLabel();
                        String a2Lebel = a2.getLabel();
                        Integer a1Int = Integer.parseInt(a1Lebel);
                        Integer a2Int = Integer.parseInt(a2Lebel);
                        a1Int.compareTo(a2Int)
                        map.put();
                        return a1Int.compareTo(a2Int);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Above is my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: it would help if you add the code as well.. it is not possible to understand the issue from the question

Comment: Help us help you - share you code, the result you're getting and the result you'd like to get

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have added my piece of code. Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this:
You do not need 2 lists. Only one. The sort method will sort the list it is passed

```
List<SelectItem> benefitList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
//add items
Comparator<SelectItem> comparator = (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1.getLabel()), Integer.parseInt(o2.getLabel()));
Collections.sort(benefitList, comparator);
```

you can use comparing int as well:

```
Comparator<SelectItem> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.getLabel()));
```

or use anonymous class if you cannot use lambda

```
Comparator<SelectItem> comparator = new Comparator<SelectItem>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(SelectItem o1, SelectItem o2) {
    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1.getLabel()), Integer.parseInt(o2.getLabel()));
  }
};
```

Comment: I can't use lamda exp.. :(